# Exception occurred executing command line. CreateProcess: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe"

Tags: eclipse, java

I have the above problem when trying to run the astparser ([found here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/)).

I have windows xp 32bit and eclipse helios.

I already have tried the -vm option in the .ini file of eclipse, but problem persists.

The error message is:

```
Exception occurred executing command line.
CreateProcess: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1253 -classpath "C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\ASTExplorer\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.6.0.v3650b.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.icu_4.2.1.v20100412.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.41.v200903070017.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\java_cup.runtime_0.10.0.v201005080400.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\javax.activation_1.1.0.v201005080500.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\javax.jws_2.0.0.v201005080400.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHITE-RABBIT\Επιφάνεια εργασίας\eclipse\plugins\javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\neo.WHI”
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe` exist on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Java somewhere without spaces in the path. It will only cause you unnecessary heartache, like this. The same goes for all your dev tools, like ant, maven, ides, sql tools, etc.

Comment: There's a space between "Program" and "Files"

Comment: From the classpath in your original post, you have eclipse installed under C:\Documents and Settings. <-- More spaces. Fix those, too.

Comment: put them in: C:\eclipse and C:\jre1.5.0_17. Still same problem.

Comment: Exception occurred executing command line.
CreateProcess: C:\jre1.5.0_17\bin\javaw.exe -Dfile.encoding=Cp1253 -classpath C:\ASTExplorer\bin;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.2.200.v20100427.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.launching_1.0.0.v20100427.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.5.0.v20100427.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.compare.core_3.5.100.I20100526-0800.jar;

Comment: Please [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the entire message, including the error code and message that it gives you.

Comment: it pops up a window saying: 'Launching ASTMain' has encountered a problem. Exception occured executing command line and below it says:

Comment: It says 'Launching ASTMain' has encountered a problem. Exception occured executing command line and below it says what i wrote above and some more (similar) paths that i am not allowed to write because of charachters limit.

Comment: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) (click the link) will let you paste an (effectively) unlimited amount of text and give you a short link to it, which you can provide in a comment. I won't be able to help much more without seeing the full message, especially the error code and message at the end of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is still only part of the command being run. You say that comes from a window that pops up? Try [these steps](http://zachxu.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-show-actual-java-command-line.html) to get at the real, full command line. You can tell the full command line because after the huge "-classpath ...", there will be other options and it will also have "astexplorer.ASTMain" in it. I'm running neither Eclipse nor Windows, so I can't easily try this out myself.

Comment: unfortunately my program won't run at all so debug view is empty. i have taken a printscreen of the message it pops up when i try right click on the project (ASTParser) run as-> java application. thanx for looking at my problem closely.
http://imageshare.web.id/images/i6me4550owtuafdzijf1.jpg

Comment: That URL doesn't show me an image, just an upload form. I know which window you're talking about, though, and it truncates the error message if it's too long. My only other suggestion at this point is to try reconstructing the command yourself. Use eclipse's .classpath file to build yourself a classpath string, and run `java -classpath <the classpath string> astexplorer.ASTMain`

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error like the one you got above so i uninstalled eclipse and reinstalled it again and this time i just changed the installation directory and i have 4-5 java versions available at the same time so i uninstalled all the versions and just installed the latest version and then in the eclipse workspace it created a base folder for me and i  changed the project folder as the source folder for java classes and files and it worked for me

Comment: Use punctuation to improve readability.